# python gevent asyncResult send different value to coroutine

Tags: python, asynchronous, gevent

It's easy to send value to different coroutine in `gevent.event.AsyncResult` like following code.

```
import gevent
from gevent.event import AsyncResult
a = AsyncResult()

def f1():
    gevent.sleep(3)
    a.set('Hello')

def f2():
    print a.get()

def f3():
    print a.get()

gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(f1),
    gevent.spawn(f2),
    gevent.spawn(f3),
])
```

But i want to send different values to different coroutine/function through f1 function, for example:
1.f1 send 'hello' to f2 so f2 can get 'hello' message through a.get()
2.f1 send 'world' to f3 so f3 can get 'world' message through a.get()
Does anyone have good solutions ? Thanks verymuch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without context for what you're really trying to accomplish, I can't say whether this makes any sense, however you could try...

Having two different async results:

```
import gevent from gevent.event
import AsyncResult
a = AsyncResult()
b = AsyncResult()

def f1():
    gevent.sleep(3)
    a.set('Hello')
    b.set('World')

def f2():
    print a.get()

def f3():
    print b.get()

gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(f1),
    gevent.spawn(f2),
    gevent.spawn(f3), ])
```

Or pass back multiple results in a data structure, and each function looks up the result they want:

```
import gevent
from gevent.event import AsyncResult
a = AsyncResult()

def f1():
    gevent.sleep(3)
    a.set({'first':'Hello', 'second':'World'})

def f2():
    print a.get()['first']

def f3():
    print a.get()['second']

gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(f1),
    gevent.spawn(f2),
    gevent.spawn(f3),
])
```

Comment: Thankyou, i use the dict as you said to solve this problem